# Download Xcode with developer account and then change account

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have a developer account now, and I can download Xcode 5.
But soon I won't need this account anymore, and I may
get a *new* (organization type) account.
My question is, will I be able to use my new organization
account to write programs with Xcode 5 I downloaded previously?
And also submit possibly with this new account?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes.

If you submit the app to the App Store using your first account, then you can use [iTunes Connect App Transfer](http://www.macrumors.com/2013/06/10/apple-updates-itunes-connect-with-app-transfer-functionality/) to transfer it to a new account.

If you work on the app *without* submitting it to the App Store, you can change account and there will be no problems (you will have to change the App ID & provisioning profiles if you obtained these with the old account).

---

**A downloaded copy of Xcode is not linked to an account**, so you can use Xcode with any account, or no account.

The limitations come with the documentation - pre-release documentation will not be available in Xcode if you don't link an account, however Xcode will still work fine without the documentation. Once you add a new account, the documentation will download and be accessible. Documentation downloaded with your current developer account will not need to be re-downloaded if you switch account.

Comment: grgarside, thanks, I just means something slightly different, I will explain what now. Say I have developer account X now. I download Xcode 5 and start working on some application now (I am not sure if I must supply my account name). Then afterwards, I **change** developer account. Will I be able to continue working on this same application with the new account? Thanks.

Comment: yes, so the idea is I will have Xcode 5 with some developer account  (say X) that I won't need in future. So my question is basically should I start working on my new application now, with **this old (X)** account? (with the possibility to change it later to new account. I won't submit the app with the old account).

Comment: @user2568508 Yes, you can. When I was developing my first iOS app, I developed with a free account, then when the time came to submit to the App Store, I purchased a developer account and updated my bundle identifier, and everything worked fine.